# Elixir Nerves Phoenix Umbrella Project - Running Phoenix error: 'CoreServices/CoreServices.h' file not found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, iot, nerves-project

Following this [Nerves Tutorial](https://hexdocs.pm/nerves/user-interfaces.html#phoenix-web-interfaces) to setup a [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework), I get this error at the end of the tutorial when trying to run the server.

```
cjsMBP15:ui cj$ mix phoenix.server
==> fs (compile)
Compiling c_src/mac/cli.c
In file included from c_src/mac/cli.c:2:
In file included from c_src/mac/cli.h:4:
c_src/mac/common.h:5:10: fatal error: 'CoreServices/CoreServices.h' file not found
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
ERROR: compile failed while processing /Users/cj/elixir_projects/nervous_espresso/deps/fs: rebar_abort
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :fs, "/Users/cj/.mix/rebar compile skip_deps=true deps_dir="/Users/cj/elixir_projects/nervous_espresso/_build/dev/lib"" command failed. You can recompile this depe
ndency with "mix deps.compile fs", update it with "mix deps.update fs" or clean it with "mix deps.clean fs"
cjsMBP15:ui cj$
```

I have recompiled, cleaned, updated [fs](https://hex.pm/packages/fs) library, but cannot seem to get it to run. What am I missing or what should I be trying?

(Please note [iot](/questions/tagged/iot) is because there is no Nerves tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `{:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},` from `mix.exs` in the phoenix UI project solved the error. It looks like there is a breaking compatibility error that is referenced https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-basic-setup-error/3189/15

Also, the `code_reloader` needs to be turned to `false` in `dev.exs`

```
config :ui, Ui.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: false,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: []
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are experiencing is an issue compiling `:fs` for Mac os. You can try updating your `brew` and ensuring that you have xcode installed.